# Pandas groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the data set below in a dataframe, df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'Date' : ['1-Jan','2-Jan','3-Jan','1-Jan','2-Jan','3-Jan'],'VAL' : [45,23,54,65,76,23]})
```

I am trying to insert a column, say 'new_col', that calculates the percent change in VAL that is grouped by ID.  So, for example, I would want the percent change from 45 to 23, 23 to 54, and then restart for ID 'B'. The below code works but it calculates the percent change regardless of ID.

```
df['new_col'] = (df['VAL'] - df['VAL'].shift(1)) / df['VAL'].shift(1)
```

I tried adding the group by function in front of it but I am still getting an error:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('ID')[(df['VAL'] - df['VAL'].shift(1)) / df['VAL'].shift(1)]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just just stick your expression in brackets onto the groupby like that.  What you need to do is use `apply` to apply a function that calculates what you want.  What you want can be calculated more simply using the `diff` method:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['VAL'].apply(lambda g: g.diff()/g.shift())
0         NaN
1   -0.488889
2    1.347826
3         NaN
4    0.169231
5   -0.697368
dtype: float64
```

As DSM notes in a comment, in this case you can do it directly with the `pct_change` method:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['VAL'].pct_change()
0         NaN
1   -0.488889
2    1.347826
3         NaN
4    0.169231
5   -0.697368
dtype: float64
```

However, it is good to be aware of how to do it with `apply` because you'll need to do things that way if you want to do a more complex operation on the groups (i.e., an operation for which there is no predefined one-shot method).

Comment: There's also the (terribly, terribly named) `.pct_change`.